# Iterating between text and integer in android using java to show a professional splash screen

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I am trying to create a splash screen to display the progress of loading an android app using the code bellow

```
    String[] launcher_message = {"Initializing\tsystem","Starting\tengine","opening\tpayment\tgateway",
        "initializing\tstack","Initializing\tsecurity","Loading\tpools","More\tsecurity\tinitialization",
        "Starting\tsystem","Loading\tapp","Updating\tlocal\tdatabase"};

private void doWork() {
    for (int progress=0; progress<101; progress+=10) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mProgress.setProgress(progress);
            for(int i = 0; i<launcher_message.length; i++) {
                loaderLabel.setText(launcher_message[i]+" "+progress+" %");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                       }
    }
}
```

My expectation is that a string should be slected from the array displayed with the percentage of it's progress from 0-100 then pick another and do the same untill all are done but what is happening is that only the last string is displayed when the progreess value is 0-10 then the first is displayed to the end.

My question is can my desire be achieved and how

Answer (score 2):

Use this like below Code:

```
public class testme {


public void doWork() {
    String[] launcher_message = {"Initializing\tsystem","Starting\tengine","opening\tpayment\tgateway",
            "initializing\tstack","Initializing\tsecurity","Loading\tpools","More\tsecurity\tinitialization",
            "Starting\tsystem","Loading\tapp","Updating\tlocal\tdatabase"};

    for (int progress = 0,i=0; progress < 101; progress += 10,i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Log.e("doWork", "doWork: "+launcher_message[i]+" "+progress+"%");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}
[image: See Output oF above code i create using plain java code. You can change as per Your requirement.]

Comment: Almost close to what I am trying but now it, what I want is the progress of each string to display through to 100 before picking another string and doing the same for all the strings in the list.
This only displays the progress simultaneously with the strings